# I have test case to automate , where the Testcase says to verify if the element is not present in the table. (Edit icon is not present)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I have test case to automate , where the Test case says to verify if the element is not present in the table. (Edit icon is not present)

I have to find out if the element doesn't exist (Edit Icon ) doesn't exist. When i tried doing this with AssertTrue /AssertFalse, iam getting error saying no such element present exception. Please help me how this can be achieved in Selenium.

Comment: welcome to SO! please read [mcve], and edit post accordingly. how your code looks like, how html structure of element looks like etc..

Comment: Possible solution:  assertThat(driver.findElements(By.xpath("selector for your element")).size() < 1, is(true));  Feel free to modify the locator.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using try catch block like below:

public boolean checkElementExists() {

```
boolean isExists = false;
try {
    isExists = driver.findElement(By.xpath('xpath'));
} catch (Throwable) { }
return isExists;
```

}

In case of element exists, isExists value will set with true and perform assert on top of this method call. If any exception raises, by default, method returns false.